# How to send the gamescore element in Javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have developed a memory game with images. The game works fine. I problem I have is with the scores. When the game is completed, the score is displayed on the screen with a button "submit". So when I click the button, the score should be added to the database. I tried using ajax, php and Javascript.

The php code for the submit button :

game.php:

```
<?php session_start();
 ?>

 <body> 
   <div align='center'>
        <button class="play-again" onclick="reset()>Play Again</button>
        <button id="sendscore" class="Go-on"><a href="gallery.php">Submit</a></button></div></p>
    </div>
```

The game logic where is calculated score:

gameply.php:

```
 <? php ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 var gamescore;
 var totalscore;

 if(matches =='8'){
   var totalscore = calcScore();
   document.getElementById("score").innerHTML= totalscore;
 }

 function calcScore(){
var tilesbonus = (matches) * 20; // 20 points for each successful tile
var timebonus = (finaltime) * 2;  // 8 points for each second
var triesbonus = (30 - moves) * 5;  // (deduct) 10 points for each try
if (tilesbonus <0) { tilesbonus = 0; }
if (timebonus <0) { timebonus = 0; }
if (triesbonus <0) { triesbonus = 0; }
totalscore = tilesbonus + timebonus + triesbonus;
return totalscore;
}


$("#sendscore").on("click",function(){
gamescore= document.getElementById("score").innerHTML;
$ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: 'server.php',
  data:{
      'gamescore': gamescore,
  },
  success: function(data)
                {
                alert('score is submitted');      }
   }) 
  });

  </script>
```

The code where it gets the ajax call and stores the score to the table:

server.php:

```
  <?php
   session_start();
   if(isset($_POST['gamescore'])){
   $username=$_SESSION['username'];
   $fetch = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
   $fetchid =mysqli_query($db, $fetch);
   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetchid)){
   $id = $row['id'];
   $username=$row['username'];
   $gamescore= $_POST['gamescore'];
   $updatescore= "UPDATE users SET score='$gamescore' WHERE id = '$id'";
   mysqli_query($db, $updatescore);

   $finalscore="UPDATE users SET sum_score = (sum_score + $gamescore) WHERE id='$id'";
   mysqli_query($db,$finalscore);
   }
   }
   ?>
```

The problem I have is when I click the submit button, the score not added to the database. The error i get is undefined symbol '$' on the line $("#sendscore").on("click",function(){

Comment: You sure request is going to `server.php`? Also I would recommend trying tools like Postman to check if your `server.php` is working alright or not.

Comment: You are open to sql-injection. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @Saharsh now i get an error undefined symbol '$' ........ for the line 
 $("#sendscore").on("click",function(){

Comment: I'm assuming that you are including the jQuery script file, if not, that would be why you are seeing the "undefined symbol $" error.

Also, how is the username variable being declared and set, since that is critical to updating the SQL.

I would also second @freek in saying that prepared SQL statements are a must in this instance.

Comment: @Uviiii that's a jQuery issue. Probably mean you are trying to call jQuery function without or before loading the library script. You can find plenty of troubleshooting methods by googling it.

Comment: @Saharsh could you give me a solution for this, because I have not used jquery before and I need some more detailed solution so i can understand it more better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not included Jquery to your file.

please add

```
 `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
```

This line before your `</html>` tag.

Comment: i tried by adding this script, still the error is not cleared.

Comment: where did you added this? you should add this before your <script> tag?

Comment: you should add it before the <`script>` tag you used.